# positioning an quote symbol before and after a quote text

Tags: html, css, position

i'm trying to position an quote symbol after and before a paragraph. i'm using absolute values. Opening my Page with different smartphones-browser e.g. iPhone 5 / iPhone 6 will cause a different results. Any Ideas! here is my Code

HTML:-

```
<div class="quoteBlock">
  <div class="blockWrap">
    <span class="headline">italian<br/>classic</span>
    <p class="quoteText">
      <span class="quoteBegin">“</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetuer adipiscing.<br/>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.<br/>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, alique, vulputate eget, arcu.<span class="quoteEnd">„</span>
    </p>
    <a class="ctaBlock">scorpi più prodotti</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#content .quoteBlock {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #D4AF95;
}

#content .blockWrap {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
#content .quoteBlock .headline {
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial, helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 23px;
}
#content .quoteText {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 15%;
  line-height: 21px;
  position: relative;
}
#content .quoteBegin { 
  color: #333; 
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 700; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 58px;
}
#content .quoteEnd { 
  color: #333; 
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 700; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 121px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the device meta tag? I'm guessing this is a 'pixel' thing.

Comment: no i didn't use any viewport meta tags

Comment: I suggest you use % values rather than exact pixel numbers - http://jsfiddle.net/sqecnos5/1/ AND add the appropriate meta tag...

Comment: or you could use blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```css
#content .quoteBlock {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #D4AF95;
}
#content .blockWrap {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
#content .quoteBlock .headline {
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial, helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 23px;
}
#content .quoteText {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 15%;
  line-height: 21px;
  position: relative;
}
#content .quoteBegin {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 58px;
}
#content .quoteEnd {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 121px;
}
blockquote {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999999;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1.2% 0;
  padding: 1% 6.3%;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
}
blockquote p {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1% 4.3%;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
}
blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: -5px;
  color: #8A8A8A;
}
blockquote:after {
  display: block;
  content: "\201D";
  font-size: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3.5%;
  top: -5px;
  color: #8A8A8A;
}
blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: .95em;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<div class="quoteBlock">
  <div class="blockWrap">
    <span class="headline">italian<br/>classic</span>
    <p class="quoteText">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetuer adipiscing.
          <br/>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
          <br/>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, alique, vulputate eget, arcu.</p><cite>scorpi più prodotti</cite>
      </blockquote>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```